# What is the meaning of $dy=dx^2$?

Tags: analysis, fractions

When I read the mathematical analysis ,I think if the differential is $dy=Adx^2$ $A$ is a function about x, what will happen? Maybe, it is not proper defined ,but I think the "function" meet $dy=A(dx)^2$ will has some fractal structure.

Comment: This question is missing *a lot* of context...

Comment: A possible geometrical meaning of $\mathrm dy= A \mathrm dx^2$ is that the slope of the function $y$ is $2Ax$

Comment: Do you mean $\mathrm dy = \mathrm d(x^2)$ or $\mathrm dy = (\mathrm dx)^2$ or did you just encounter this somewhere as just $dy = dx^2$ ?

Comment: @Nick I mean $dy=(dx)^2$

Comment: @lanse2pty: Then, that doesn't make sense without proper context. $$y =\int{\mathrm dx}\cdot\mathrm dx$$ is something I have never seen before.

Answer (score 1):

These are [differentials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function). They're handy for linear approximations and errors. Essentially, it's really just another way of representing a derivative.

Since everybody is differentiating, I figure I'll integrate instead.

$$\int dy = \int A \ d(x^2).$$
I take it that $A$ is a constant, so $y = A x^2 + C$. If $A(x)$ were a function of $x$, we would make the substitution $u=x^2$, and have $$y = \int A(\sqrt{u}) \ du,$$ which is kind of awkward.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathrm dy = \mathrm dx^2 \\
\Rightarrow \mathrm dy = 2x\cdot\mathrm dx \\
\Rightarrow \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = 2x$

Usually,

$d\left(f(x)\right) = f'(x) \cdot \mathrm dx$

Comment: Can you explain the first implication...?

Comment: @Nameless: This is sometimes called "exact differentiation" : $\mathrm d(x^n) = nx^{n-1}\cdot \mathrm dx$

Comment: No, I meant $dy = dx^2 \implies dy = 2xdx$.

Comment: @Nameless: That's exactly what I explained. $\mathrm dy = \mathrm dx^2 \iff dy = 2x^{2-1} \mathrm dx$

Comment: Is it $d(x^2)$ or $(dx)^2$?

Comment: @user291957: I've interpretted it as $d(x^2)$ as the other was unlikely... Now, if it was $(dx)^2$, that's a whole other story. Hopefully, it wasn't $d^2 (x)$ ... Yeah, I'm too scared to ask OP.

Comment: So could you please edit your answer to describe even that.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$dy=Adx^2=(2xA)dx$. In fact, $df(x)=f'(x)dx$.